# Couldn't create instance of class. Koin

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, clean-architecture, koin

I had injected all dependencies via Koin, added App file to Manifest, added dependencies to all modules of my app. And I have an error:

```
ATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.testtaskfooddelivery, PID: 3251
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testtaskfooddelivery/com.example.testtaskfooddelivery.MainActivity}: org.koin.core.error.InstanceCreationException: Could not create instance for [Factory:'com.example.testtaskfooddelivery.presentation.MainViewModel']
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                                                                                    Caused by: org.koin.core.error.InstanceCreationException: Could not create instance for [Factory:'com.example.testtaskfooddelivery.presentation.MainViewModel']
                                                                                                        at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceFactory.create(InstanceFactory.kt:60)
                                                                                                        at org.koin.core.instance.FactoryInstanceFactory.get(FactoryInstanceFactory.kt:38)
                                                                                                        at org.koin.core.registry.InstanceRegistry.resolveInstance$koin_core(InstanceRegistry.kt:103)
                                                                                                        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveValue(Scope.kt:223)
                                                                                                        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveInstance(Scope.kt:211)
                                                                                                        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.get(Scope.kt:193)
                                                                                                        at org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.factory.DefaultViewModelFactory.create(DefaultViewModelFactory.kt:11)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$Factory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:83)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:187)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:153)
                                                                                                        at org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.ViewModelResolverKt.get(ViewModelResolver.kt:23)
                                                                                                        at org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.ViewModelResolverKt.resolveInstance(ViewModelResolver.kt:12)
                                                                                                        at org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.scope.ScopeExtKt.getViewModel(ScopeExt.kt:86)
                                                                                                        at org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.scope.ScopeExtKt.getViewModel(ScopeExt.kt:72)
                                                                                                        at org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.ext.android.ViewModelStoreOwnerExtKt.getViewModel(ViewModelStoreOwnerExt.kt:68)
                                                                                                        at com.example.testtaskfooddelivery.presentation.MainFragment$special$$inlined$viewModel$default$1.invoke(ViewModelStoreOwnerExt.kt:75)
                                                                                                        at com.example.testtaskfooddelivery.presentation.MainFragment$special$$inlined$viewModel$default$1.invoke(ViewModelStoreOwnerExt.kt:40)
                                                                                                        at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
                                                                                                        at com.example.testtaskfooddelivery.presentation.MainFragment.getViewModel(MainFragment.kt:17)
                                                                                                        at com.example.testtaskfooddelivery.presentation.MainFragment.onViewCreated(MainFragment.kt:37)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3128)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:552)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1433)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2977)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:2888)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3129)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:552)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1433)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2977)
2023-06-11 15:34:54.142  3251-3251  AndroidRuntime          com.example.testtaskfooddelivery     E      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2895)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:263)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:351)
                                                                                                        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:251)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1333)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6992)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2780)
                                                                                                        ... 9 more
                                                                                                    Caused by: org.koin.core.error.InstanceCreationException: Could not create instance for [Singleton:'com.example.domain.GetListOfCategoryUseCase']
                                                                                                        at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceFactory.create(InstanceFactory.kt:60)
                                                                                                        at org.koin.core.instance.SingleInstanceFactory.create(SingleInstanceFactory.kt:46)
                                                                                                        at org.koin.core.instance.SingleInstanceFactory$get$1.invoke(SingleInstanceFactory.kt:53)
                                                                                                        at org.koin.core.instance.SingleInstanceFactory$get$1.invoke(SingleInstanceFactory.kt:51)
                                                                                                        at org.koin.mp.KoinPlatformTools.synchronized(PlatformToolsJVM.kt:20)
                                                                                                        at org.koin.core.instance.SingleInstanceFactory.get(SingleInstanceFactory.kt:51)
                                                                                                        at org.koin.core.registry.InstanceRegistry.resolveInstance$koin_core(InstanceRegistry.kt:103)
                                                                                                        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveValue(Scope.kt:223)
                                                                                                        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveInstance(Scope.kt:211)
                                                                                                        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.get(Scope.kt:193)
                                                                                                        at com.example.testtaskfooddelivery.di.AppDiKt$mainModule$1$5.invoke(AppDi.kt:58)
                                                                                                        at com.example.testtaskfooddelivery.di.AppDiKt$mainModule$1$5.invoke(AppDi.kt:46)
                                                                                                        at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceFactory.create(InstanceFactory.kt:53)
                                                                                                        ... 48 more
                                                                                                    Caused by: org.koin.core.error.InstanceCreationException: Could not create instance for [Singleton:'com.example.domain.MainRepository']
                                                                                                        at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceFactory.create(InstanceFactory.kt:60)
                                                                                                        at org.koin.core.instance.SingleInstanceFactory.create(SingleInstanceFactory.kt:46)
                                                                                                        at org.koin.core.instance.SingleInstanceFactory$get$1.invoke(SingleInstanceFactory.kt:53)
                                                                                                        at org.koin.core.instance.SingleInstanceFactory$get$1.invoke(SingleInstanceFactory.kt:51)
                                                                                                        at org.koin.mp.KoinPlatformTools.synchronized(PlatformToolsJVM.kt:20)
                                                                                                        at org.koin.core.instance.SingleInstanceFactory.get(SingleInstanceFactory.kt:51)
                                                                                                        at org.koin.core.registry.InstanceRegistry.resolveInstance$koin_core(InstanceRegistry.kt:103)
                                                                                                        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveValue(Scope.kt:223)
                                                                                                        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveInstance(Scope.kt:211)
                                                                                                        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.get(Scope.kt:193)
                                                                                                        at com.example.testtaskfooddelivery.di.AppDiKt$mainModule$1$4.invoke(AppDi.kt:58)
                                                                                                        at com.example.testtaskfooddelivery.di.AppDiKt$mainModule$1$4.invoke(AppDi.kt:40)
                                                                                                        at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceFactory.create(InstanceFactory.kt:53)
                                                                                                        ... 60 more
                                                                                                    Caused by: org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: No definition found for class:'com.example.data.network.GetDataFromNetworkImpl'. Check your definitions!
                                                                                                        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.throwDefinitionNotFound(Scope.kt:273)
                                                                                                        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveValue(Scope.kt:243)
                                                                                                        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveInstance(Scope.kt:211)
                                                                                                        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.get(Scope.kt:193)
                                                                                                        at com.example.testtaskfooddelivery.di.AppDiKt$mainModule$1$3.invoke(AppDi.kt:58)
                                                                                                        at com.example.testtaskfooddelivery.di.AppDiKt$mainModule$1$3.invoke(AppDi.kt:34)
                                                                                                        at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceFactory.create(InstanceFactory.kt:53)
                                                                                                        ... 72 more
2023-06-11 15:34:54.284  2477-2505  ResourcesManager        com.android.systemui                 E  failed to add asset path /data/app/com.example.testtaskfooddelivery-LbHj0V13OemQV6VyEiMHLA==/base.apk
```

My "App" file:

```
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        startKoin{
            androidLogger(Level.ERROR)
            androidContext(this@App)
            modules(mainModule)
        }
    }
}
```

My Koin module:

```
val mainModule = module {

    single<GetDataApiService> {
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create()
    }

    single<GetDataFromNetwork> {
        GetDataFromNetworkImpl(
            getDataApiService = get())
    }
//
//
    single<MainRepository> {
        MainRepositoryImpl(
            getDataFromNetworkImpl = get()
        )
    }

    single {
        GetListOfCategoryUseCase(
            repository = get()
        )
    }

    viewModel {
        MainViewModel(
            getListOfCategoryUseCase = get()
        )
    }
}
```

When I tried to discard dependencies one by one, I figured out, problem appears when I add GetDataFromNetworkImpl. Here it is:

```
class GetDataFromNetworkImpl(
    private val getDataApiService: GetDataApiService
    ): GetDataFromNetwork {
    override suspend fun getListOfCategory(): Response<DataCategories> {
        return getDataApiService.getCategories()
    }
}
```

Any advice?! Let me know if it needs more information.